# Whacky characters in Word file (Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, ms-word, special-characters

Has anyone ever seen this kind of gobbledy-gook show up in the middle of a file before? I have a Word file that won't open, and I'm wondering if this is the cause. My gut tells me that the author pasted an image or link directly from the web, and that threw the whole thing out of whack. If I clean this stuff up in Notepad and then try to open the file, it works fine. Just wondering if I'm looking at anything malicious, and if there's an existing way to clean out such material before trying to open a file.

> IHDR             %ÛVÊ    sBIT   |.w‚    PLTEÿÿÿ   UÂÓ~    tRNS @æØf    bKGD ˆ  H
>   cmPPJCmp0712   Om•¥
>   IDAT Óc`˜cl×    IEND®B`‚µ   D                                                                >ÐÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>          àÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>   D   j a v a s c r i p t : t o p . d o c j s . n e x t _ h i t ( 1 5 )   S   D >d                     à à                                        ð,   ² 
>   ð
>    s 
>   ð     A    Á\
>     ÿ     Ã    ‚Ãˆ   ¿     h t t p : / / i p l a w . b n a . c o m / i p l w / i m a g e s / n e x >t _ h i t . g i f   n e x t   h i t   ÐÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>          àÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>   \   j a v a s c r i p t : t o p . d o c j s . n e x t _ h i t ( 1 5 )   yXô; H¯,‚]Ä…'c    ¥«     >ð       €b ðÓ     åcLã“¹³ß´îO)sÞ6’ÿ ¯       F        n ð§   åcLã“¹³ß´îO)sÞ6’ÿ‰PNG
>
> IHDR             %ÛVÊ    sBIT   |.w‚    PLTEÿÿÿ   UÂÓ~    tRNS @æØf    bKGD ˆ  H
>   cmPPJCmp0712   Om•¥
>   IDAT Óc`˜cl×    IEND®B`‚µ   D                                                                >ÐÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>          àÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>   D   j a v a s c r i p t : t o p . d o c j s . n e x t _ h i t ( 1 5 )   S   D >d                     à à                                        ð,   ² 
>   ð
>    s 
>   ð     A     Á\
>     ÿ     Ã    ‚Ãˆ   ¿     h t t p : / / i p l a w . b n a . c o m / i p l w / i m a g e s / n e x >t _ h i t . g i f   n e x t   h i t   ÐÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>          àÉêyùºÎ Œ‚ ª K©
>   \   j a v a s c r i p t : t o p . d o c j s . n e x t _ h i t ( 1 5 )   yXô; H¯,‚]Ä…'c    ¥«     >ð      €b ðÓ     åcLã“¹³ß´îO)sÞ6’ÿ ¯       f#       n ð§   åcLã“¹³ß´îO)sÞ6’ÿ‰PNG
>
> IHDR             %ÛVÊ    sBIT   |.w‚    PLTEÿÿÿ   UÂÓ~    tRNS @æØf    bKGD ˆ  H

Comment: IHDR / IDAT/ IEND are names of chunk identifiers in PNG graphics files ...

Comment: Thanks, @AlexK.! Does that make it likely, then, that the whole thing is graphic encoding?

Comment: I would say so, something screwy happened somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexK., determined that this was graphics encoding.  It turned out to be a file corrupted by a user copying/pasting from online.